# Mark 10.18 “Good Teacher“ Why do you call Me good?” Jesus replied. “No one is good except God alone

Tags: jesus

My question is around Jesus, that he always and only claimed to be  the  'Son of Man' and not to actually be GOD, Simply you are either God or you are not God and there is only one God,

Even in front of Pontius Pilate the Roman Governor for Judea,  Jesus did not claim for himself to be God or even a King,
Jesus said  ' You (Pilate) ask or state that I am a king ( this is your (Pilate's) statement and not mine (Jesus) ! )..., .... 'but I (Jesus) have been born to be a witness to the truth'

Yes, very important to understand that Jesus was not on the same level as God according to the scriptures, but yet he is the still the Messiah and ' a witness to the truth' and forms part of the trinity with the Holy Spirit.

This concept is very clear from either the Koran, Torah or the New Testament.

YES the church teachers have allowed distorted scriptural interpretations to suit themselves for Milenia and its not the churches fault, it's our own fault for not carefully studying the original
scriptures to extract the truths and understand very simple concepts.

Mark 10:18 is one example, Only God is truly 'Good' so don't call me Good he admonishes and corrects
this man's statement,  when the man said to Jesus that he is the 'Good Teacher' instead of simply
a Teacher.
Why does Jesus admonish this man, simply because Jesus wants us his followers to get the meanings correct,
Jesus stands for the full and only truth, he cannot afford for his followers to get
the logic wrong.
For if Jesus is not truly 'Good' that means he is fallible has some sin and is quite human obviously, this logic from the mouth of Jesus himself is clear and very simple here and easy to understand.

Another example is only God knows the hour ( Not even I, Jesus,
knows the hour ),
Frankly in other words, if Jesus was God he would have known the hour of the Son of Man's Return.

Jesus always claimed to be the 'Son of Man' Jesus never claimed to be actually God,
Son of Man is definitely not the same status as God which some have been teaching.

Do you know how many times the scriptures quote Jesus claimed to be the Son of Man?
Do you know how many times Jesus claimed to be God?
If you do bother to find out Please please post the numbers here.

Happily do your own research and report your feedback here on this thread
will be most welcome what you think about that.

Thank You.

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your contribution.  Please take the tour (link below) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: "Which one of you convicts me of sin? If I tell the truth, why do you not believe me?"
(John 8:46,ESV)

Comment: Jesus answered them, “I have shown you many good works from the Father; for which of them are you going to stone me?” 33 The Jews answered him, “It is not for a good work that we are going to stone you but for blasphemy, because you, being a man, make yourself God.” 
(John 10:32–33, ESV).

Comment: I am confused about what you are asking here.  Is it, "Did Jesus claim to be God?" or, is the apparent contradiction about only God being good?

Comment: The question is about the status of Jesus in Christian teaching, I recently saw a  Jewish Rabbi preaching about the status of Jesus and how to accept that Christians are not worshipping an Idole but see Jesus as part of the Trinity, Judaism rejects Jesus as God, Divine Being, intermediary between humans and God, messiah or holy. Belief in the Trinity is also held to be incompatible with Judaism. Muslims Hold Jesus as a Prophet but a a major Prophet.

Comment: John 10 32, Even Jesus followers could not fully understand his relationship with God , they thought he was claiming to be God yet Jesus stated I am the Son of Man when he could just as easily claimed to be God as in the above

Comment: John 8 46, obviously Jesus could not promote a devout pure life if he himself was living in sin and yet he was living as a Man and had to be extremely disciplined but he went to extreme length and pointed out he is not 'good' himself as above. we can look at a lot of texts and say it is also written, but we have to confront whether or not Jesus claimed to be God and I dont find that in any of the new testament

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and you may think it is not important topic but we have three major religions Christianity Judaism and Islam who all whorship the same God but cannot agree on the status of Jesus, there should be more clarity and we need open thinking around this

Comment: The only question asked here is about the number of times Jesus is called 'Son of man' which is a text-search question and is off-topic on this site. Aside from that, this is a rant, not a substantiated question.

Comment: Not a rant but a fair legitimate and poignant question, was Jesus Son of Man, son of God ( after the Pentecost ) also  or was he in fact God when he never claimed to be God  when the holy spirit was poured out.  My question is about if Jesus is considered to be the same level God, this is a very important conclusion  for other religions like Islam and Juduaism as above,

Comment: @user48152 - I dont have all the answers, Jesus is part of the Trinity but he is not on the same level of God, hard to comprehend but this looks to be the reality as per the examples I set forth. This is a confusion for Rabbis and Islam alike who are both taking keener look these days at the life and meaning of Jesus, I guess for Christians we should rejoice about that.

Comment: @pinkpanther Understood. The trinity is, shall we say, *extra-biblical*, however your perspective on Jesus not being God is in accord with the scripture. That is what I was pointing toward. It’s a good question, and welcome! It may be closed as being a duplicate tho.

Comment: @user48152 thank you for responses and feedback.

Comment: I agree with you @NigelJ and that's why I voted to close too. A statement like "that he always and only claimed to be the 'Son of Man' and not to actually be GOD" is *false*. For instance, John 8:58 (in reference to God's name in Exodus 3:14).

Comment: It is written (John 17:3) saying, “ And this is eternal life, that they may know You, the only true God, and Jesus Christ whom You have sent.” (See Colossians 2:2 as well). It may be possible to close the question related with the knowledge of the eternal life (also see 1John 1:1-3), the Lord Jesus Christ and the Son of the ONLY true God. But, confronting the truth is inescapable “ For we can do nothing against the truth, but for the truth. (2 Cor. 13:8)” (very good question, upvoted, +1)

Comment: @pinkpanther Don’t be discouraged by the closure. You’ll refine question asking format in time and I expect will enhance the site with thinking not confined by traditional dogma.

Comment: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/31222/are-there-any-linguistic-especially-greek-cues-on-how-mark-1018-is-to-be-inte

Answer (score 2):

Here is the answer to the question:

Jesus is called the "Son of God" about 45 times in the NT

Jesus is called the "Son of Man" more than 80 times.